# Entity Framework - New child entities not added to database on saving parent entity (only in production environment)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am facing a weird issue in an application. I have the following code which updates a parent entity and add new child entities.

```
    Item item = db.Items.Find(Id);

    if (newSubItems.Count() > 0)
    {
        newSubItems.ForEach(x =>
        {
            var subItem = new SubItem();
            subItem.Name = x.Name;

            item.SubItems.Add(subItem);
        });
    }

    item.ModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
    item.ModifiedBy = UserId;

    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;

    using (var s = db.Database.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel: IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
    {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        s.Commit();

        logger.info("Updated successfully.");
    }
```

This code is working fine in my local environment. If I supply new sub-items, those are added successfully to the respective table.

The models are given below.

```
    public partial class Item
    {
        public Item()
        {
            this.SubItems = new HashSet<SubItem>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class SubItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public Item Item { get; set; }
    }
```

However this is not working in my production environment as expected. Parent entity is updated, but new child entities are not added if there are no existing child entities. I checked the logs and I can see that "Updated successfully" is logged. If there is at-least 1 child entity for the parent, then new child entities are added successfully.

So now as a work around in production environment, I am re-adding the sub-items again after the first save operation using the below code.

```
    int subItemsCount = db.SubItems.Where(a => a.ItemId == item.Id).Count();

    if (subItemsCount == 0 && newSubItems.Count() > 0)
    {
        logger.info(string.Format("Sub-items are not added for Id - {0}. Adding those again.", item.Id));

        newSubItems.ForEach(x =>
        {
            var subItem = new SubItem();
            subItem.Name = x.Name;
            subItem.ItemId = item.Id;

            db.SubItems.Add(subItem);
        });

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        logger.info(string.Format("Sub-items re-added successfully for Id - {0}.", item.Id));
    }
```

Now at looking the logs from production environment, I can see that the message "Sub-items are not added for Id" is logged many times and sub-items are added successfully in the second save operation.

Wondering if any one know the reason for this weird behavior in specific environment alone.

Comment: Try including the SubItems (using .Include) when you get the item details `Item item = db.Items.Find(Id);` use `Item item = db.Items.Include(i => i.SubItems).Where(i => i.Id == Id);`

Comment: Also you might not need the `db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;` as you are not in detached mode (unless you have explicitly disabled change tracking)

Comment: @Developer Thanks for the suggestions. I believe, by default all child entities should be loaded and `.Include` is needed, only if I manually disabled `LazyLoadingEnabled` property . I will try removing the second statement of updating state to `modified` as you suggested, but still I am not sure whether that statement will cause an issue like this.

Comment: Could you please check whether the foreign key relations are set properly in the production database? Also in your `SubItem` entity, the navigational property for `Item` is missing to make the EF aware about the Item foreign key - not sure whether you have set it using the fluent syntax

Comment: @Developer FK relations are correct in production. I even tried with production db copy in my dev environment which is working fine. While adding the sample model here, I missed navigational property. Correcting it now.

Answer (score 1):

In your first approach you should check if `item.SubItems` for null before doing `item.SubItems.Add()` on it.

If it is null then initialize  like `item.SubItems = new ICollection<SubItem>();`

In your second approach,in this code block you are not assigning ItemId

```
 newSubItems.ForEach(x =>
        {
            var subItem = new SubItem();
            subItem.Name = x.Name;
            subItem.ItemId = item.Id;/* missing line*/
            db.SubItems.Add(subItem);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My second approach did work fine for me. You are right that I missed one line `subItem.ItemId = item.Id;`. I have updated the question with that. Now coming to the first approach. If the value is null like you said, shouldn't it throw `NullReferenceException`, when I try to add items to it using `db.SubItems.Add(subItem);`?

Comment: @Manu I am wondering that of the three properties in your SubItem class you are only assigning name. What about ItemId property in your original code?

Comment: `Id` is an auto-incremented identity element. And I believe `ItemId` is not needed to be specified explicitly, as I am adding sub-item object into the child collection of item object. I guess that relation should be automatically resolved by entity framework.  And above all, this code is working fine in my local environment.